# Android : changing background colour

Tags: android, colors, background

I am trying to write my own program which allow basic features like changing `background colour`. I find that many entries in this website and on the internet talks about menu colour rather than the background of the layout in the Main activity. What I want to do is described perfectly in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5RK9nlmp5N4) but I want to change the colour from the menus.

Is there some way of achieving this? My code here hangs - not responding when run in virtual for kitkat.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RadioGroup radioGroup;
    RadioButton radioButtonwhite, radioButton2gray;
    View view;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
        radioButtonwhite = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButtonwhite);
        radioButton2gray = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton2gray);

        final View view = findViewById(R.id.screen);

        radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, @IdRes int checkedId) {

                if (checkedId == R.id.radioButton2gray) {
                    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
                }

            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: use `view = findViewById(R.id.screen);`. You have already created `View view;`  .

Comment: I cannot do that; that will cause the view in "view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);" to become an error. The "final" declaration is forced although it may look redundant.

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.android_examples.com.layoutbackgroundprogrammatically.MainActivity"
android:id="@+id/Layout" >
```

In your Activity.class

```
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

 RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout ) findViewById(R.id.Layout);

 radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
 radioButtonwhite = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButtonwhite);
 radioButton2gray = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton2gray);
 radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, @IdRes int checkedId) {

        if (checkedId == R.id.radioButton2gray) {
            relativeLayout .setBackgroundResource(R.color.blue);
        }

    }
});

 }
```

Here is the screenshot where you can find color resources

[image: color resource]

```
 }
```

Comment: I changed my code from Constraint to Relative. I had to put it as final but now the colour "Gray" - declared in strings value file is detected as an error. Everything else looks good.

Comment: colors should be declared in color.xml under values directory. Please correct your code

Comment: ok I've fixed my color code as I'm still a beginner in this. Upon running, the virtual hangs - "not responding" when i click gray. So what can I do next?

Comment: I found another example where I can change the colour only after launching new screen (activity). so this case has been solved. It will be left open in case anyone finds a method - hopefully not too troublesome to code.